# Foreign-Keys for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, polymorphic-associations

i'm refactoring a db structure and have a little problem.
This DB have various tables with same structure, like:

People -> People_contacts

Activities -> Activities_contacts

Now, i want to create only one Contact table, and use an ENUM() to distinguish from the nature of the parent (for search requirements and data reversibility)

the structure will be:

People -> Contacts[People]

Activities -> Contacts[Activities]

But now i need to put a Foreign-key, and based on the ENUM property distinguish from two different tables...
How i can effort this? There are a way or is better maintain the old tables?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish can you let us know what are you trying to do?

Comment: the idea is put some foreign keys, to accomplish OnDelete -> delete contacts, but the reference is not based only the primary key of the companion table, because i use the ENUM to define witch one is. - the alternative is to launch a trigger, but i prefer to use foreign keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you are using view? if the `People_contacts` and `Activities_contacts` are exactly the same, you can try this:

```
create view `test` as select *,'People' as Type from `People_contacts` union select *,'Activities' from `Activities _contacts` union;
```

and then select what you want from the view:

```
select * from `test` where Type = 'People' and .....
```

and your query answer should be this

```
+----+------+   +--------+
| ID | Data |...| Type   |
+----+------+   +--------+
| 1  | foo  |...| People |
| 2  | foo  |...| People |
+----+------+   +--------+
```

Comment: Hmmm... i like this solution, can make me happy and do less work in programming...

Comment: Using a view is always an elegant solution. Anyways please note that this way actually you are keeping the old tables, and the views are just for reading. You can insert and update in some kind of views, as explained here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/view-updatability.html, but when the view is merging to tables, you can forget this. So you will have one view for reading and two tables for writing. you know your tables so you can consider if this is ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a declared foreign key, pointing to one table or another depending on a field. 
You can do a few things, but none of then are really clean.

1. You can  have the integer field, and the enum, but do not declare the field as a foreign key. You will have to implement all the logic by yourself, and it will be harder to maintain, and harder to decouple database from programing.
2. You can have 2 nullable foreign keys (people_id and activity_id), and forget the enum field. if one FK is null, the other will have the real relation. This is better since you declare the foreign keys as usual and the model is stronger
3. If you prefer to keep your contact table clean, you can have a relation table where you put this dirty stuff. So in this table you store the contact_id, and the id of the activity or the person, as explained in whatever 1 or 2

**But anyways, probably you are obfuscated and you dont need to have the foreign key in the contact table. I would bet you will always access first the people or the activities table, so you probably can change this tables, and add a contact_id foreign key. In the contact table you just need to add, if you dont have it already, de id primary key, and delete de ENUM field, and the foreign keys, since you dont really need them**

Comment: Yeah, i hope i will put that, but i need a one-to-many relationship with many contacts...

Comment: So,you can try with a view as h.bahadorzadeh says.But please note that this way actually you are keeping the old tables,and the views are just for reading (much easier and with less performance). You can insert and update in some kind of views, as explained here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/view-updatability.html, but when the view is merging to tables, you can forget this. So you will have one view for reading and two tables for writing.Thats why, in this case, for me the best would be a new table, and my point 2, but using a view could be ok.you know your tables so you can decide.

Comment: finally, i need foreign keys only for delete contacts when a row on peoples or activities table would be deleted. Maybe best solution could be an 'on delete' trigger?

Comment: So, in the end, unique table and triggers on updates. This will cause some limitation in deletion, but i've figured out how to solve that problem

Comment: I wouldnt say limitations, i d say that you will learn a lot about triggers and conditional queries :-)

Comment: Yeah but when i have to delete an object and i select it by contact i have to perform 2 queries, because i have to list all the people and after delete by id, this because the trigger lock the table and i couldn't launch the query